# Get request -to display data fro api

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, api, http-get

```
http://api.testmy.co/user/files
```

I Need to fetch data and to display that data in my tableview like `grid view`. I am new to this type of handling api, get request and all. If any one can explain about this `"Get type request"`  & how to display the data in my tableview like grid view.I only have this url to do ( for example only above url).

Can any help help me with some tutorial or git-hub or any idea about it.Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I help you to fetch the response.Once you save the response data to array or dictionar you can show to the tableview.

```
-(void)getResponse  
{
 //just give your URL instead of my URL
 NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL  URLWithString:@"http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/search.ashx?query=London&num_of_results=3&format=json&key=xkq544hkar4m69qujdgujn7w"]];

 [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

 [request setValue:@"application/json;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];

 NSError *err;

 NSURLResponse *response;

 NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request   returningResponse:&response error:&err];

 //You need to check response.Once you get the response copy that and paste in ONLINE JSON VIEWER.If you do this clearly you can get the correct results.    

 //After that it depends upon the json format whether it is DICTIONARY or ARRAY 

 //If it(RESPONSE) starts with dictionary({...}),you need to write coding blow like this

 NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &err];

 NSArray *array=[[jsonDict objectForKey:@"search_api"]objectForKey:@"result"];

 //But if it(RESPONSE) starts with array([...]),you need to write coding blow like this

 NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &err];
}
```

If you want to get grid view,you better to use CollectionView.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [self getResponse];
  UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
  flowLayout.scrollDirection =  UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical;
  //Register the custom cell for collection view
  UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomCell" bundle:nil];
  [collectionViewHorizontalVertical registerNib:cellNib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cvCell"];
}

//Collection View Delegates method
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
  return  1;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  return jsonArray.count;
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cvCell";
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
  cell.imgViewCollection.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

  return cell;
}
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
  return CGSizeMake(200, 200); //Please give your required size
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you code bro..But i even don't know how to start with my URL for get data and to display

Comment: so only i asked for any tutorial or demo project

Comment: ok bro.let give me some demo project or tutorial link to do from scratch for my question

Comment: Also please send me you url.From that what you want to get the output exactly like image or anything else?

Comment: that is confidical,so send me your mail id or skype id bro

Comment: Now come to gmail.I will send my mail id from there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93861/discussion-between-user3182143-and-jj1).